# JFrame: Fixed width but dynamic height

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, dimension

is there any way to set the width of the JFrame fixed, but height of the JFrame dynamic? For an example,

```
width = 1200 
Height = will be based on number of elements
```

in other words

```
width = 1200 
Height = pack()
```

please help!

Comment: I think you're best bet would be to restrict the width of the content pane by overriding it's `getPreferredSize` method

Comment: Do not set fixed sizes. Please look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Comment: Also consider `BorderLayout.EAST` or `BorderLayout.WEST`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a constant for width and a variable for height, and then use [the regular setPreferredSize method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that don't stop the frame from been resized (width wise) - which is how I read the question. Also, we're generally discouraged from using setPreferredSize

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need this, but for future people looking at this thread, you could declare a width constant, and set min & max size of the frame.

```
setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, 0));
setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
setResizable(false);
```

Subsequent calls to pack() will enforce the width, but allow the height to be dynamically calculated.